# Reason for container restarting

Tags: azure-aks, azure-monitoring

I am using Azure Kubernetes Service however, according to the Azure Monitoring, I saw that the uptime changes when I am checking for CPU. How do I find the reason upon why the container had automatically restarted? Because as seen in the picture, it had automatically updated the last reported time = uptime shown.

[Last reported detail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6GPg3.png)

I would like to know where to find the reason upon how and why the container had automatically restarted. But I do not know how and why.

Comment: SO is a programming Q&A platform and this question is not about programming. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Please delete this.

Answer (score 0):

There can be a number of reasons why a container has restarted.
Azure Kubernetes Cluster on it's own doesn't restart the containers. However,  there are chances because of Node's downtime. You need to your SLA regarding. The pod might have run into issue, you can check the event logs regarding that.